# How to get simple chart.js to refresh on a web page

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I have a simple bar chart on a test site, using `chart.js` - the chart `myChart.js` on a site with a simple bar chart. The chart gets updated once a week (by regenerating `myChart.js`).

The chart works fine, and the page refreshes properly (either on loading the page or refreshing with F5) but the chart is always the same as it was last time - even if `myChart.js` is removed from the server!

However, a ctrl-F5 refresh does show the latest update.

I've tried page refreshing through metadata, using JS to update the page and a whole host of other examples I've found online, but so far I cannot make it work.

I don't need dynamically updating charts - just a chart that reflects the content of `myChart.js` when a page is loaded.

The minimal page HTML is as below - followed by someone else's sample myChart.js. Any thoughts on how to do this would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Show current time to see if page has updated -->
        <p>Date/Time: <span id="datetime"></span></p>

        <script>
            var dt = new Date();
            document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
        </script>
        
        
        <!-- Create the convas -->
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>        
        
        <!-- get chart.js from CDN -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- and display it -->
        <script src="myChart.js"></script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
          data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - solved this one. In reality it's trivial - even though it's taken me about 25 hours to figure it out!

It's the javascript that is being cached. When I transfer the whole of the JS into `<script>` on the page HTML it works fine.

So I decided to add an (ignored) parameter:

```
<script src="myChart.js?<?php echo filemtime('myChart.js'); ?>"></script>
```

which means that the call will look like:

```
<script src="myChart.js?1604618883"></script>
```

where 1604618883 will change (and myChart.js will be reloaded) whenever myChart.js is changed.

Phew!!